# Oracle 11 query to combine multiple rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11.
There are 3 columns: ID, ParentID, Level, Name.

Level 1 is the highest level, then level 2, then level 3.

For ex:

```
ID  ParentID  Level Name
10   12         3   Name10
11   (null)     1   Name11
12   11         2   Name12
```

How can I create a query that will return them in 1 row, like below:

```
ID  ParentID  NameParent    Child1  NameChild1  Child2  NameChild2
11  (null)    Name11        12      Name12      10      Name10
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can write a [rather long] query to do it in three levels. But... do you want the query for three levels only, or for any number of levels? Also, what if a parent has multiple children? That won't fit well in the result. Will it?

Comment: There are only 3 levels, and a parent can only have 1 child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table with itself to combine all three rows into a single one:

```
select
  t1.id, t1.parentid, t1.name as nameparent,
  t2.id as child1, t2.name as namechild1,
  t3.id as child2, t3.name as namechild2  
from my_table t1
join my_table t2 on t2.parentid = t1.id
join my_table t3 on t3.parentid = t2.id
where t1.parentid is null
```